# design pattern for interpreting object type to use

Tags: design-patterns

I have a situation where we need to find out the type of object that should handle given specification and reuse a object. Here is an example:

```
interface ICar {
    int getMaxSpeed();
}

class Mercedes implements ICar {}
class Ferrari implements ICar {}
class Jauguar implements ICar {}
```

Use:

```
for(Spec spec : specs) { //spec will contain only a blob.. not a actual car type; I need to interpret it somehow
     //do something here to match spec with type of car..
     ICar car = getSpecificCarSomehowWithoutSwitchCase(spec);
}
```

I thought of two possible ways of doing this:

1. Use Builder\Abstract Factory pattern to interpret and create car (or return existing object already created)
2. Add "IsMe" method to ICar, have pooled instances of Car objects and call them with spec as parameter and return true if it is the case.

I like approach #2, specially because I can and want to reuse the objects already created. I looked at object pool design pattern but "checkout" method doesn't take a key\crietrion to find objects.

Did I miss some pattern\approach?

Thanks in advance,
-Neel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use abstract factory, it seems that you know the pattern already, if not:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern 
Another good site for C# is:
http://www.dofactory.com/

If that is not enough, I will write you some pseudo code tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something like this:

```
foreach (var factory in availableFactories)
{
   if (factory.IsSuitableFor(thisAbstractItem)
   {
      factory.CreateBasedOn(thisAbstractItem);
   };
};
```

The caller asks the factory if they can handle the item. So the factory implementation looks like:

```
public bool IsSuitableFor(AbstractBase thisAbstractItem)
{
    return thisAbstractItem is anItemICanWorkWith;
}
```

It works well for what I need and it's nice and simple. I wonder if you can take the idea of asking the specific classes if they handle the specific case and alter it for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a behavioral pattern. I would consider the Chain Of Command (or Command) pattern to determine handling of logic which would then invoke a Prototyped (reusable) instance of one of your car classes

Comment: It is called 'Chain of responsibility', and I am not sure that is what he needs.

Comment: Thanks @ValentinYanakiev but you are incorrect: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39166/Using-the-Chain-Of-Command-Design-Pattern-Concepts. As i said it's also called the **Command** pattern and he could in fact implement it to handle his logic. I was not referring to the Chain of responsibility pattern as defined here: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility

Comment: Command is a behavioural pattern which is meant to encapsulate an action and abstract it from the subject. It is not meant to be used for creation. For creation you have creational patterns, such as Factory, Abstract Factory, Builder, etc.

Comment: I still disagree; he needs a behavior to implement an action: 'interpret and create car' ... 'and call them with spec'. The behavior of his logic is the primary goal which will then determine to 'create' or 'reuse' an ICar instance. Most of the time all OOP solutions will be of a composite nature and NOT JUST one pattern